# Proving the standard matrix U of T to be orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation, orthonormal

So my class is getting into orthogonality, however, our reading assignments haven't been touching on transformations.  I have this proof problem that I cannot seem to get around.  Does anyone have any advice?  Here is the problem:

> > Let $W \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a subspace.  Consider a linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $T(\mathbf{x}) \cdot T(\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y}$ for all $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.
> >
> > Prove that the standard matrix $U$ of $T$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: What do you know about orthogonal matrices?$T^{-1}T = 1.$

Comment: Think about what you can do with adjoints in an inner product.

Comment: Don, all I know for orthogonal matrices are they they are made up of column vectors that are orthonormal and each vector is orthogonal to every other vector (where the dot product is 0).  I do know about $T^{-1}T$ = 1, but do you use 1 to mean the identity matrix?

Comment: @Don Larynx : what you said is true for all invertible matrices. Don't you mean $TT^{t}=I$ , where $T^{t}$ is the transpose?

Comment: As one of the instructors for the class you're taking, I can definitely say that we'd rather you just ask us than throw it out here.

Comment: Alright I'll do that, Ryan.

Comment: Well since you're here and it's late: my standard hint is that a matrix is orthogonal if and only if its columns are orthonormal.  And how do you define the columns of the standard matrix of $T$?

Comment: @user99680: Yes, sorry.

Comment: @Don Larynx : No problem; I've done similar, around $\aleph_0$ times.

Answer (score 1):

By the condition given, we have $\begin{align} (U\textbf{x})^{T}(U\textbf{y}) &= (\textbf{x}^{T}U^{T})(U\textbf{y}) \\&= \textbf{x}^{T}(U^{T}U)\textbf{y} \\&=\textbf{x}^{T}\textbf{y} \end{align}$ for all $\textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, where the first equality is by the properties of transposes of products of matrices. But the last equality holds if and only if $U^{T}U = I_{n}$, so $U$ is an orthogonal matrix, as desired.

To prove this "if and only if" statement explicitly, it remains to show the "only if" direction.  The standard matrix of $T$ has $j$-th column $T(\textbf{e}_{j})$ where $\{\textbf{e}_{1}, ..., \textbf{e}_{n}\}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.  Now, consider arbitrary $\textbf{e}_{i}, \textbf{e}_{k} \in \{\textbf{e}_{1}, ..., \textbf{e}_{n}\}$.  By the condition given, we have $\
T(\textbf{e}_{i}) \cdot T(\textbf{e}_{k}) = \textbf{e}_{i} \cdot \textbf{e}_{k}$, which is $0$ if $i \neq k$ or $1$ if $i = k$.  Thus, we have shown that the columns of the standard matrix $U$ are orthonormal, proving that $U$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

**BIG HINT**

> $$T(\vec{x})*T(\vec{y}) = (\vec{x})T^{T}T(\vec{y})$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$x^T U^T Uy = x^Ty$$
**for all** $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Now let $x=e_i$ and $y=e_j$, where $e_k$ denotes the vector zero at all locations except at $k$, where it is $1$. Now note that for all $i,j$, we have
$$e_i^T U^T Ue_j = \sum_{k=1}^n U(k,i)U(k,j)$$
and
$$e_i^Te_j = \delta_{ij}$$
Use this to conclude what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One of the definitions of Orthogonal matrix is that the matrix sends orthogonal vectors to orthogonal vectors. You can show the matrix associated to $T$ does that by using that , for the standard basis $e_1,e_2,..,e_n$ , $T(e_i)T(e_j)=<e_i,e_j>=0$ , so orthogonal vectors are preserved ( using linearity of $T$ , the result extends.)